# VBA macro for extracting website source to a cell returns an #VALUE! error in excel

Tags: excel, vba, url

I am new in VBA macros, and I'm using one that extracts an URL source and when I try to use it to fill the contents of a particular cell in excel i get a #VALUE! error in a cell. Can someone help?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Function GetSource(url As String) As String  

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")    
   .Open "GET", url        
   .Send   
   Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .Readystate = 4  
   GetSource = .responsetext  
   .abort  
End With 

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the #VALUE error when I omit "http://"; when I include it your function works well for what seem to be "well formed" pages. For others I seem to fail.

For debugging purposes I created a reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0" and changed code to

```
Function GetSource(url As String) As String
Dim O As MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    Set O = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    O.Open "GET", url
    O.send
    GetSource = O.responseText
    O.abort
    Set O = Nothing

End Function
```